# If Link 1 is clicked, make link 2 unclickable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a feedback form offering two links.

If someone clicks the first link, I don't want them to be able to click the second link and vice versa.

How would I go about doing this? I assume some sort of cookies to block the click or can it be done at ip level?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide code examples with code that you have tired.

Comment: @nakashu I don't know who is `tired` but it seems like it's you :p

Comment: If you're talking on the page itself, it's a simple bit of javascript/jquery.  But if you want to persist this so that they can't just F5 the page and click the other button (as implied by asking about cookies/blocking), it's a whole other board game.

Comment: I think it's an understandable question without code from the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be a Javascript solution:

```
<script> 
function clicktoDisable(link) 
     link.onclick = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
     }
   }   
</script>
<a href="next.html" onclick="clicktoDisable(this);">Click here!</a>
```

Comment: Surprising number of up-votes given there appears to be only one link in this answer while the question has 4 paragraphs (incl title, excl thanks), 3 of which mention "2 links"

Comment: @freedomn-m It's the same example at 2 links! You just have to set the onclick event correctly. When this is done the element will be blocked when you click. This can also be adjusted.

Comment: Well, no, `clicktoDisable(this)` will not be the same for 2 links, it will be "very" different and non-obvious how to change.  Also strange to see an `onlick=` answer on a jquery question.

Comment: @freedomn-m The question has the tags (Javascript and jQuery) There's nothing reprehensible about posting something that hopefully is helpful. I have read the question only skimming so probably the misunderstanding. I will add another option to the answer.

Comment: Clearly, as you're getting some nice upvotes.  I'm just adding commentary.

Comment: @HendrikKölbel you are disabling the clicked link. OP is asking to disable the **other** link on click on one. Your answer is completely unrelated to OP question

Comment: @LelioFaieta I know, I know. Excuse me for that. I read to you at first. I'd still like to leave my answer standing because it might help others.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it will remove href from other link. I have updated the code so if one has attr href then remove the href attr from the other.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a').click(function(e){
var attr = $(this).attr('href');
if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
$(document).find('a').not(this).removeAttr('href');
}
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
```

Comment: But for example, if there are 10 links on the page, ALL will be disabled except the clicked link. But good code example!

Comment: ye you can use parent div for the ankers, instead of $(document).find like $(this).parents('div').find

Comment: its just general solution, can be changed according to situation.